# Do we need to call join() if we are using Recursiveaction of ForkJoinPool framework?

Tags: java, join, fork, forkjoinpool

Do we need to call join() if we are using RecursiveAction of ForkJoinPool framework?

e.g.:

```
left.fork()
right.fork()
```

or

```
left.fork()
right.fork()
left.join()
right.join()
```

If left and right both updating a common data structure, is there a reason to call join for both of left and right parts?

Thanks in advance,
Burcak

Answer (score 0):

I understood hat we definitely need to join the results after we fork them.
I have used invokeAll() method so that forks and joins  are handled by Java.

Best wishes,
Burcak